# c# Program error "the requested security protocol is not supported"

Tags: c#

I used below code

```
try
{
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCal  lback = delegate { return true; };
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

    WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(site);
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    req.Method = "POST";
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("data=" + "null");
    req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
    Stream os = req.GetRequestStream();
    os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    os.Close();
    WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());

    MessageBox.Show(sr.ReadToEnd().Trim());
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    MessageBox.Show(exc.Message.ToString());
}
```

The program run in my computer without error but when run in my customer`s computer show below error
"the requested security protocol is not supported"

in continue I change code to below

```
try
{
    WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(site);
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    req.Method = "POST";
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("data=" + "null");
    req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
    Stream os = req.GetRequestStream();
    os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    os.Close();
    WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());


    MessageBox.Show(sr.ReadToEnd().Trim());
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    MessageBox.Show(exc.Message.ToString());
}
```

but again error.

my customer`s computer is win7 by donNet 4.

Comment: Here are couple of suggestions.
1) If you are running .net 3.5 this support link provides you suggestions on how to address this. 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3154518/support-for-tls-system-default-versions-included-in-the-net-framework
2) The other option is to take a look at the link below if you can compile your code using .net 4.7

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls

Comment: Have you tried to use `SecurityProtocolType.Tls12` in addition or instead of current `SecurityProtocol`?

Comment: I checked SecurityProtocolType one by one ...

my customer`s computer working only by SecurityProtocolType.Tls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set below code and test

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
```